# access first and last element in nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multidimensional-array, hashmap

I'm using `group_by`, to group `energy_delta` column every month, so here the result from the `group_by` method

```
{
  "2017-04-01 00:00:00 UTC": [
    {
      "id": null,
      "created_at": "2017-04-01T02:14:19.870Z",
      "energy_delta": 1
    },
    {
      "id": null,
      "created_at": "2017-04-01T02:14:19.979Z",
      "energy_delta": 3
    },
    {
      "id": null,
      "created_at": "2017-04-04T15:00:01.136Z",
      "energy_delta": 10
    }
],
 "2017-01-01 00:00:00 UTC": [
    {
      "id": null,
      "created_at": "2017-01-31T02:14:21.300Z",
      "energy_delta": 167
    },
    {
      "id": null,
      "created_at": "2017-01-31T02:14:21.311Z",
      "energy_delta": 184
    },
    {
      "id": null,
      "created_at": "2017-01-30T02:14:21.322Z",
      "energy_delta": 200
    }
]}
```

Now I have this nested hash and I want to subtract the last `energy_delta` from the first `energy_delta` for every month. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want the last value or the difference between the last and the first value? Should the values be sorted by date first?

Comment: yes, first the value will be sorted by date, then find the difference between last and first value

Comment: Okay. Its not what the accepted answer does.

Comment: sorry I was not careful and forget that it should sorted first

Answer (score 3):

Given you have your input stored as a hash in `input`, you can do something like this:

```
input.collect { |month, entries| { month => entries.first[:energy_delta] - entries.last[:energy_delta] } }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your readings are already sorted by date, you can use :

```
grouped_by_month.each do |month, readings|
  first_value = readings.first[:energy_delta]
  last_value  = readings.last[:energy_delta]
  puts month
  puts last_value - first_value
end
```

It outputs :

```
2017-04-01 00:00:00 UTC
9
2017-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
33
```

If you want to sort them by date, you could use :

```
grouped_by_month.each do |month, readings|
  sorted_readings = readings.sort_by{ |reading| reading[:created_at] }
  first_value = sorted_readings.first[:energy_delta]
  last_value  = sorted_readings.last[:energy_delta]
  puts month
  puts last_value - first_value
end
```

It outputs :

```
2017-04-01 00:00:00 UTC
9
2017-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
-16
```